# Save Telegram chat in doc file?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there any way to save text messages from some my Telegram chats to doc of txt file? Maybe some browser extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can dump your history using [this project](https://github.com/tvdstaaij/telegram-history-dump).